# Three.JS wireframe material - all polygons vs. just edges

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using ThreeJS in a project and noticed that older versions render wireframes differently than newer versions, and I can't figure out how to revert (which I'd prefer).

This fiddle using release 54 renders only the exterior edges of the object drawn with a wireframe material: http://jsfiddle.net/ksRyQ/
or as pictured here in case this is platform specific (I'm on mac chrome):

[image]

On the other hand, when I run the same code locally using the newer version r61 I see each polygon's edge, as in:

[image]

the code in both cases is simple:

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    wireframe: true
});
```

I'm sure I could make the cube out of lines or something, but I'd rather actually understand the issue.

Any clues? Is there a setting for this or something that can be tweaked? Secondarily, you'll note that right now that code is using the canvas renderer, although I plan to use the webGL renderer, but the same phenomenon is true with both (even though there are other differences).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you want to render a wireframe of a given `geometry`, you can now use this pattern:

```
var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry ); // or WireframeGeometry( geometry )

var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } );

var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );

scene.add( wireframe );
```

`WireframeGeometry` will render all edges. `EdgesGeometry` will render the hard edges only.

Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539130/display-wireframe-and-solid-color/31541369#31541369) on how to render both a model and its wireframe.

EDIT: updated to three.js.r.82

Comment: Just to elaborate, you see the diagonals because support for quad faces was dropped from Three.js, and so CubeGeometry and others are now implemented using triangles.

Comment: Got it, thanks Yaku, that definitely answers my basic question -- if I want something else I'll just have to draw it differently.

Comment: I'm on rev 71 and don't have EdgesGeometry or WireframeGeometry, what can I use instead?

Comment: I saw the older edits to this answer, I'm getting `Only THREE.Mesh can be rendered by the Firefly renderer. Use THREE.Mesh to draw lines.`, so is there any way I can add lines of the shape that aren't diagonal?

Comment: @kuhaku rev 71 is 2+ years old. Upgrade to the current version. Make a new post if you have questions.

Comment: It's not up to me, I'm on Autodesk Viewer and that's the version they use with it...

Comment: How do you make this work with animated objects that have a changing mesh?

Comment: Yeah what about animations?