# ThreeJs Box Outline

Tags: three.js

I am making something in three.js and it had cubes (or rectangles) with outlines, because wireframe now renders diagonals I couldn't use that, I cant use Images either, and I tried boxhelper, I need something like the wireframe in *older* versions, but not transparent, is there anyway to to this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153705/three-js-wireframe-material-all-polygons-vs-just-edges/

Comment: @WestLangley        boxhelper only draws a few edges, I had already seen that question.

Comment: The link refers to `EdgesHelper`.