# Draw lines of mesh on SphereGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to draw lines of a THREE.mesh whose geometry is done with `SphereGeometry` and material with `MeshBasicMaterial`.

To achieve this, I have used the following snippet code:

```
    var segments = 32
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, segments, segments, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x900000});
      var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(sphere);
```

This snippet doesn't produce the expected lines.

Instead of above code, I tried also to do:

```
var sphere = new THREE.Object3D();
  sphere.add( new THREE.LineSegments(

        new THREE.Geometry(),

        new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
          color: 0xffffff,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.5
        })

        ));

  sphere.add( new THREE.Mesh(

        new THREE.Geometry(),

        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          color: 0x156289,
        emissive: 0x072534,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading
        })

        ));

  scene.add(sphere);
```

The lines of mesh aren't displayed too.

I use three.min.js version 74.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539130/display-wireframe-and-solid-color/31541369#31541369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use THREE.WireframeHelper class.

```js
var wireframe = new THREE.WireframeHelper( sphere, 0x00ff00 );
scene.add( wireframe );
```

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/WireframeHelper