# Drawing edges of a mesh in Three.js

Tags: three.js, mesh

Is there something as *Stroke* to draw the edges of a mesh?

I would like to have my object to look like this:

[image: Black stroked, white filled object]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was outdated, and has been updated.

---

If you want to render only the edges of your mesh, you can use `EdgesGeometry`.

```
var geometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( mesh.geometry );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );

var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );

scene.add( wireframe );
```

You can also use `THREE.WireframeGeometry`.

For an example showing how to render both edges and faces, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539130/display-wireframe-and-solid-color/31541369#31541369).

three.js r.94

Comment: Thanks,

but is it possible to render both the edges and the faces?