Three.js render the boundary lines of a cube mesh
I tried setting the wireframe prop as true to render the edges as lines. However, since the mesh is made out of triangles, all it's edges get visible. I only want to render the boundary lines from the cube!
wireframe
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "red", opacity: 1, side: 2, wireframe: true, }) );

Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36472653/1461008

@WestLangley Yep, you have been first… deleted.

thanks for the guidance, Guys I came up with another issue when using the edgeGeometry. It's related to the mesh.position:
please take a look!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78741837/edges-geometry-draw-boundary-edges-from-a-mesh-that-is-not-located-at-the-orig

@WestLangley and

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz please take a look too
