# Javascript threejs 3D draw solid cubic with border

Tags: three.js

I follow `threejs` example, `webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html`. My project is to use Threejs to make a container loading plan. So I want to make solid cubic with a border. something we could see with/without border difference.

[image: image with border],[image: image without border]

I could use multi-material, but then my drag and drop is broken. The code snippet in creating Geometry3 is commented.

**My question** is: how to make solid cubic with border and at the same time could be drag and drop?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - draggable cubes</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script src="js/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;
            var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
            var cubes = [];
            var plane = new THREE.Plane();
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
            offset = new THREE.Vector3(),
            intersection = new THREE.Vector3(),
            INTERSECTED, SELECTED;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 10;

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
                controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
                controls.noZoom = false;
                controls.noPan = false;
                controls.staticMoving = true;
                controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x505050 ) );

                
                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 5, 7);
                var hex =  0xff0000;
                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++ ) {                 
                    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex );
                }
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5,wireframe:true } );
                var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                cubes.push( cube );
     
                var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2,4, 5);              
                var hex2 = 0x009fff;
                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry2.faces.length; i++ ) {                
                    geometry2.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex2 );
                }                  
                var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5,wireframe:true } );
                var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );             
                cubes.push( cube2 );

                var geometry3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,3,4);
                var hex3 = 0x0f0ff0;
                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry3.faces.length; i++ ) {
                    geometry3.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex3 );
                }              
    /*          var darkMaterial3= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffcc } );
                var wireframeMaterial3= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0f0000, wireframe: true, transparent: false } ); 
                var multiMaterial3= [ darkMaterial3, wireframeMaterial3 ];          
                var cube3 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry3,multiMaterial3);*/
                var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5,wireframe:true } );
                var cube3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material3 );   
                cubes.push( cube3 );
                
                scene.add(cube);
                scene.add(cube2);
                scene.add(cube3);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.sortObjects = false;

                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                
                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

                renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
                renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }

            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();

                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

                if ( SELECTED ) {
                    if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {
                        SELECTED.position.copy( intersection.sub( offset ) );
                    }
                    return;
                }

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cubes );
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
                        INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                        INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();

                        plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(
                            camera.getWorldDirection( plane.normal ),
                            INTERSECTED.position );
                    }
                    container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                } else {
                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
                    INTERSECTED = null;
                    container.style.cursor = 'auto';
                }
            }

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( cubes );

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    controls.enabled = false;
                    SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                    if ( raycaster.ray.intersectPlane( plane, intersection ) ) {
                        offset.copy( intersection ).sub( SELECTED.position );
                    }
                    container.style.cursor = 'move';
                }
            }

            function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                controls.enabled = true;
                if ( INTERSECTED ) {
                    SELECTED = null;
                }
                container.style.cursor = 'auto';
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
                stats.update();
            }

            function render() {
                controls.update();
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a `WireframeGeometry` or `EdgesGeometry` as a child of each draggable object.

```js
scene.add( object );
objects.push( object );

// wireframe
var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( object.geometry );
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000 } );
var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
object.add( wireframe );
```

Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31541369/1461008).

three.js r.144

Comment: Excellent!! Fast and correct answer. How to make line bold? When I increase line width, it seems it has maximum value.

Comment: By God, this is the only thing that helped me with my problem.  I had cubes rendered with linesegments and they looked great, until I used the Orbitcontrols to move the camera, and the cubes would stay but the lines disappeared.  Setting the renderorder fixed it!  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using **EdgesHelper**

```
      this.scene.add(image3D);

      edges                             =   new THREE.EdgesHelper(image3D, 0x808080);
      edges.material.linewidth          =   3;

      this.scene.add(edges);
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: `EdgesHelper` was removed from the library in three.js r.81.

Comment: I am using r82, it is better looking for my case. For container loading 3D, this is better solution. Is it depreciated? Anyway, I am using r82, and it works.

Comment: @user84592 Read your console warning message: "THREE.EdgesHelper has been removed. Use THREE.EdgesGeometry instead."

Comment: @WestLangley You are right, this API is depreciated. But our business people like this type of edge.

Comment: @Jorge Abraham Jimenez Molina: I could not get mouse event now after I am using this API. Any Idea?

Comment: Finally I am using @WestLangle. It has mouse event and using wireframe:false.

Comment: @user84592  you need to add events to the canvas container.

this.canva_container.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onWindowMouseMoveHandler, false);