# Problems rendering edge lines as SVG - three.js

Tags: svg, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to draw edge lines on 3D objects rendered in three.js, however the lines do not render correctly when using the SVGRenderer.

**Apply edge lines:**

```
  var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( mesh.geometry );
  var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, linewidth: 4 } );
  var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
  mesh.add( wireframe );
```

(Edges code taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31541369/165673))

This works as expected with the WebGLRenderer:

https://jsfiddle.net/8p7jja9L/23/

[image]

But lines are obscured when using the SVGRenderer:

https://jsfiddle.net/8p7jja9L/24/

[image]

---

(**NOTE:** NEITHER version renders correctly in Chrome, due to this [issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10357). Use Firefox to see an accurate representation of the WebGL version.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a limitation of `SVGRenderer`. There is no depth-testing as there is with `WebGLRenderer`.

The best you can do is set

```
wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
```

This will force the wireframe to render after the mesh. But the entire wireframe will be rendered, giving the appearance of a transparent mesh.

three.js r.88

Comment: Thank you- however, I couldn't even get this solution to work. The renderOrder does not change - see https://jsfiddle.net/8p7jja9L/30/

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Great, that worked (to the degree you explained). Thank you