# Showing single side of wireframe - three.js

Tags: three.js

three.js materials have a [`side`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.side) attribute which controls whether the front and/or back side faces of a mesh get rendered. Is there a way to do the same thing with wireframes, so that only the front-facing edges get rendered?

**Showing backside of a cube:**

```
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xFF9800, 
    side: THREE.BackSide,
    opacity: 1//0
  });
```

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/8p7jja9L/34/

**Trying to show frontside of wireframe:**

```
  var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( mesh.geometry );
  var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { 
    color: 0x000000, 
    linewidth: 4,
    side: THREE.FrontSide
  } );
  var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
  mesh.add( wireframe );

  wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
```

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/8p7jja9L/35/

Comment: You need to make it clear you are asking about `THREE.SVGRenderer`.

Comment: @WestLangley the `side` attribute is set on the material, should not be renderer specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply add `wireframe: true` to the material and specify the side you want to render:

https://jsfiddle.net/8p7jja9L/39/

```
  material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xFF9800, 
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    wireframe: true <---
  });
```

this will render a single side of the wireframe for three.js' box geometry. If this is not the wireframe you imagined, you may need to construct a box out of planes or use a tool like blender to create the wireframe you desire.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do it using the EdgesGeometry, but I think the way you demonstrated is the best I can hope for. Thanks-

Comment: As of v112 on Jan 11, 2020, the frontside does not change wireframe.  Both sides are visible now.  unfortunately

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539130/display-wireframe-and-solid-color