# In Three.js Wireframe on top of Geometry

Tags: three.js

In Three.js is there a simple way of adding a wireframe on top of a geometry? I want it to be able to go on/off, and move with the original geometry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539130/1461008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [THREE.WireframeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/WireframeGeometry) for this. A `WireframeGeometry` can be used to create an instance of `THREE.LineSegments` that can be added as a child to your actual 3D object. In this way, it keeps the transformation of its parent. Check out the following demo to see this approach in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/y1v2q4p6/2/