# Three.js - Extra faces created when exporting model from Blender

Tags: three.js, blender

Three.js version: **71**

Blender version: **2.75a**

I want to export wireframe models from blender and have them appear in my Three.js scene exactly how they appear in Blender. This is so I can use them as outline borders for my models. For example, here is the wireframe model of the default cube that is there when you start up blender:

[image: wireframe model of default Blender cube inside Blender]

Here is the JSON for this model after I exported it:

```
{
    "uvs": [],
    "name": "CubeGeometry.1",
    "materials": [{
        "wireframe": true,
        "DbgName": "Material",
        "depthWrite": true,
        "transparent": false,
        "depthTest": true,
        "specularCoef": 50,
        "colorAmbient": [0.64,0.64,0.64],
        "opacity": 1,
        "vertexColors": false,
        "DbgIndex": 0,
        "DbgColor": 15658734,
        "shading": "phong",
        "visible": true,
        "colorEmissive": [0,0,0],
        "blending": "NormalBlending",
        "colorSpecular": [0.5,0.5,0.5]
    }],
    "faces": [35,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,35,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,6,7,35,0,4,5,1,0,0,4,7,1,35,1,5,6,2,0,1,7,6,2,35,2,6,7,3,0,2,6,5,3,35,4,0,3,7,0,4,0,3,5],
    "vertices": [1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
    "metadata": {
        "uvs": 0,
        "materials": 1,
        "generator": "io_three",
        "vertices": 8,
        "faces": 6,
        "normals": 8,
        "type": "Geometry",
        "version": 3,
        "colors": 0
    },
    "normals": [0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],
    "colors": []
}
```

Notice how there are 6 faces. I want it to appear exactly like this in my Three.js scene. However, extra faces get drawn. It's usually because for some reason Three.js is connecting corner vertices that weren't connected in Blender. Here is how it looks after I load it into my scene:

[image: wireframe model when loaded into Three.js scene]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153705/three-js-wireframe-material-all-polygons-vs-just-edges/20154589#20154589

Comment: From that answer, I used **THREE.EdgesHelper** like so:

`var egh = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x00ffff );
egh.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( egh );`

That worked, so please state that as your answer, and I'll accept it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to render a cube or box in wireframe mode but without diagonals.

One way to do that is with `EdgesHelper`, like so:

```
var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0xff0000 );
helper.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( helper );
```

You can also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153705/three-js-wireframe-material-all-polygons-vs-just-edges/20154589#20154589).

three.js r.71